# Count numbers with same digits in a sorted int array in O(log n) time

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I came across an interview question that required the candidate to count all numbers in an array with the same digits.
for example:

Count all numbers that share the same digits with int input = 394
int[] arr = {1, 14, 101, 349, 439, 745, 934}

the function would return 3, since 439, 934, 349 share the same digits.
The question is how do you solve this in O(log n) time? Im still new to the Big O concept and apart from O(n) and O(n^2)... i am having trouble understanding how to archieve O(log n).

My first thought was as follows:
I would calculate the sum of digits of all elements in the array. If the sum is equal they contain of the same of the digits as the input number.

```
      int counter = 0;

      while (num > 0) {
         int digitSum += num % 10;
         num = num / 10;
      }
      for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      int k = arr[i];

      while (k > 0) {
          int sumOfDigits += k % 10;
          k = k/10;
      }
      if(sumOfDigits == digitSum) {
       counter++;
      }
}
```

I know this would take at least O(n) time but im having trouble finding a better solution.

Comment: How can you count the number of things without counting all the things? If you can preprocess you'd be able to know some things you could skip; but you'd still have to preprocess everything.

Comment: I suppose you could permute the digits of the input (394, 349, 934, 943, 439, 493), and then just search for all those numbers in the array.

Comment: To expand on Andy's comment, for each digit permutation, you use a binary search to find the index of the number in the array. If it's found, you count identical numbers to the left and the right of the index.

Comment: _If the sum is equal they contain of the same of the digits as the input number._ - What about 295?

Comment: I cant see how you could do this in log n time. What if the whole list is valid. You would need to look at each value. Best you could do is linear

Comment: You cannot solve this in `O(log(n))`.  Also the processing step you want to do is to calculate the sorted permutation of digits.  This is a somewhat complicated operation.  To give you an idea, in Python I would do that with `''.join(sorted(str(n)))`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks I havent thought about that. I can ignore all the numbers with less more digits. But then again my entire solution doesnt work as JoeC pointed out.

It seems like I'ts impossible to solve in (log n) time. I guess the most straight forward approach would be to sort the digits of all the numbers in ascending order and then just add them to a List. If the numbers already in the list I'd increase the counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer was given by Andy Turner and JB Nizet but unfortunately only as a comment:

For this to work we must assume: the size of the input number is bounded, the integers in the array are disjoint and n is the number of elements in the array.

1. Compute all permutations of the input number digits. Some of the permutations may be the same if the number has repeated digits, take them only once. This takes O(1) time and the number of permutations is also O(1).
2. For each permutation look up the corresponding number in the array using binary search and count all the hits. This takes O(log n).

In total you get a run time of O(log n).

Note that this is only practical if the bound on the input number is rather low. If the input number can have say 20 digits it is much better to use an O(n) method unless n is really huge.

Comment: Thank you! I definately try your solution

Comment: This assumes that the array comes in sorted order.  If I asked in an interview, I'd be sure to have a non-sorted array.  Also even with 10 digit numbers, you're getting into the millions of lookups.

Comment: @btilly What would you suggest to do if the array is unsorted? Oh yea and you are right, what if the input is longer than the array or the array only contains a single permutation of the input..

Comment: @BCuracao See the answer that I suggested.  That approach has worked well for a number of Project Euler problems for me.

Comment: @btilly It is clear that this algorithm is not practical in most cases because of the huge constant. But the question was to find an O(log n) algorithm, which this clearly is. Your approach will be much faster in most cases, but is has  a time complexity O(n) or even O(n log n) depending on map implementation.

Comment: @Henry It is not just not practical.  It is wrong if the array is not sorted.

Comment: @btilly See the title "... in a sorted int array ...".

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess the array to construct a Map, by "string representing the sorted digits" of the numbers in an array that map to that normalized representation.  After that step, individual lookups are `O(1)` or `O(log(n))` depending on the map chosen.  It doesn't even matter how many numbers match, because you're just returning a preconstructed array.

So the lookup can indeed be made very fast.  But only if you either discount the preprocessing step, or amortize it over many lookups.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "construct a Map, by "string representing the sorted digits" of the numbers in an array that map to that normalized representation" . I dont understand sorry. Do you have an example?

Comment: @BCuracao Suppose you have a function `normalize(n)` that takes a number `n` like 2018 and returns a string of the digits sorted, like `'0128'`.  Then you'd want a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) whose keys are the strings returned by normalize, and whose values are arrays of all of the numbers which mapped to that string.  Call that `lookup`.  Then `lookup.get(normalize(n))` will be your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is almost O(n) as number of digit in the input is very small compare to the given array size (n).

Idea is to get the minimum possible number from each element and compare with the corresponding value of the input number

```
public static void main(String []args){

    int input = 394;
    int[] arr = {1, 14, 101, 349, 439, 745, 934};


    int ans = 0;
    int hold = getMin(input);
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(hold == getMin( arr[i] ))
        {
            ans++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(ans);
}

public static int getMin(int n)
{
    int hold[] = new int[10];
    while( n > 0)
    {
        hold[n % 10]++;
        n /= 10;
    }

    int ans = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < hold.length; i++)
    {
        while(hold[i] > 0)
        {
            ans = ans * 10 + i;
            hold[i]--;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```